# avoid Cartesian product checking for pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, cartesian-product

I have two tables in SQL Server 2014:

1. Table A contains three columns: Group, Proc, and Date
2. Table B contains four columns: Proc1, Proc2, Start, End

Table B is a list of pairs of Procs that should not appear in the same Group of Table A if the minimum Date among the group is between Start and End. I'm trying to find the groups in Table A that violate this rule, but the problem is that Table A has 60M groups each with up to 100 rows and Table B has 65000 pairs.

Other deets:

- End can be NULL
- Proc1 and Proc2 are always length 5 characters, but Proc may be any length

My strategy was to

1. For each group in A, get the minimum date AND stuff all unique values of Proc separated by commas (the field never contains commas) into a new field Procs. Yielding table C with Group MinDate Procs.
2. Take Cartesian Product of C and B where (i) MinDate between Start and End (or > Start and End is NULL) AND (ii) The length of Procs is reduced by 10 if I replace instances of Proc1 and Proc2 within it to be the empty string.

This process works (on a subset of the data), but I'm looking for suggestions on how to extend it to the full dataset.

Please let me know if you would like any other details. Thanks!

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with joins.  It would help if you had a unique identifier for each row in `b`.

The approach is to join the tables together and then count the number of violations for each row in `b`:

```
select a.group, b.id, count(distinct a.proc) as num_procs
from a join
     b
     on a.proc in (b.proc1, b.proc2) and
        a.date between b1.start and coalesce(b1.end, getdate())
group by a.group, b.id
having count(distinct a.proc) = 2;
```

If you don't have `b.id`, you can use the four columns to identify each row.

Your specific data issues with the length of `proc` is a separate issue.  You should fix your data so fields that should match between two tables actually have the same type.